# will setting the onload attribute after an element is loaded still run the handler?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What is supposed to happen if you set the onload attribute of an element after it has already loaded? Is the handler executed immediately or is it ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. It is ignored. Events happen when they happen, event handlers that aren't bound in time don't fire.

Answer (score 0):

can you just given an example for it that you asking about , in my thinking this code may helps you :

```
 function loadScript(url, callback){    
        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";

        if (script.readyState){  //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                        script.readyState == "complete"){
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            script.onload = function(){
                callback();
            };
        }

        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.cdn.com/first.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    loadScript("http://your.cdn.com/second.js", function(){
        //initialization code
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I am loading an image but I assume the same concept applies. Didn't know about readyState.

Comment: script.onload = function(){
                callback();
            };  you can use callbakc() function for loading the head script  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); is used for load the head script...